# two date ranges input all days into database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database with a possible 10 dates in input into each entry. The User will choose a start and end date and I want all the dates to be inputted into the database for my calender page.

```
$date1 = '2013-01-31';
$date2 = '2013-02-05';

for($one = $date1;$one>$date2;$one = strtotime(date('m/d/Y',$one)." -1 day"))
{
    echo $one;
}
```

firstly I need to extract all the dates. The above does not work. Meaning dates 31/01/02/03/04/05 need to be inputted into the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime makes this so much easier:

**For PHP 5.3+ Users**

```
$start    = new DateTime('2013-01-31');
$end      = new DateTime('2013-02-05');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt)
{
  echo $dt->format("m/d/Y") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**For PHP 5.2 Users**

```
$start    = new DateTime('2013-01-31');
$end      = new DateTime('2013-02-05');
while ($start <= $end)
{
    echo $start->format("m/d/Y") . PHP_EOL;
    $start->modify("+1 day");
}
```

**reference**

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)
- [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? This works with PHP 5.3 or newer: http://3v4l.org/edH1G

Comment: @JohnConde running 5.2 - i'll upgrade to 5.4 then. I have it available.

Comment: full upgrade to 5.4 done. code worked a treat. Thanks. Now I need to research what I am looking at. :)

Comment: LOL, I just updated the code to work in PHP 5.2! But good for you. Glad it works!